# Winform ListView Background Color in LargeIcon View

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

I am using standard .NET ListView and I would like to set background color in the View=LargeIcon setting. When I set ListViewItem.BackgroundColor, only text background is set.

[image: ListView Background color]

Comment: Why dont you set *ListView BackColor* the same as the item?

Comment: That sets the BackColor for the whole ListView. I would like to have white ListView background and Yellow rectangle arround the Item.

Comment: The problem is in your item icon. It doesnt cover the whole rectangle. Open your icon image and fill with the desired color or draw directly on the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a few days late, but in case you are still after a solution I have found something that might help.  I found the solution after looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19785964/340045).

You will need to derive your own version of the ListView control and add some custom drawing, but this will not result in too much extra code:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
        : base()
    {
        OwnerDraw = true;
        DrawItem += MyListView_DrawItem;
    }

    private void MyListView_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SolidBrush itemBrush = new SolidBrush(e.Item.BackColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(itemBrush, e.Item.Bounds);
        }

        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

I used this new control on a new form and I added 2 items using the designer and set the background color of the items to 'Gold'.  Here was the result:

[image: Example of ListView item background that covers more than just the text.]

Comment: Thank you! That works wery well. And I dont even need to derive the List because OwnerDraw and DrawItem are publicly available.