# Add Image to ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How to add Images to Listview (C# WinForm)?

My problem is that I have to insert 3 images to Listview in column 1,2 and 8 like this image below.

My code:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
//do something to add Image 1
//do something to add Image 2
lvi.SubItems.Add("Sell");
lvi.SubItems.Add("100");
lvi.SubItems.Add("ABC");
lvi.SubItems.Add("10,99");
lvi.SubItems.Add("OK");
//do something to add Image 3

listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

[image]

Any recommendation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView with [OwnerDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx) set to `true` and handle all the drawing inside the `DrawSubItem` event. There are many examples. E.g. [Extended ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13006/Extended-ListView). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9096724/115272) can be handy, too.